# Java renewable timer for text change

Tags: java, android

I need to make a "typing..." implementation, which will change back to f.e. "online" status, unless renewed.
So, basically each time i get "typing" notification I want to set "typing" status for 2 seconds and then change it back, but if I get another "typing" notification, the countdown must reset.
How can I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: @Amy now its just setToolbarSubTitle(getString(R.string.typing)); on status receive, and back on another status receive, but I want to make it to hang for 2 secs and change back, unless renewed

Comment: Use Handler with post delayed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Amy I got the answer. For those, who interested:

First, create Handler and Runnable:

```
    composingHandler = new Handler();
    composingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setToolbarSubTitle(getString(R.string.online));
        }
    };
```

Then in code:

```
    setToolbarSubTitle(getString(R.string.typing));                              
    composingHandler.removeCallbacks(composingRunnable);
    composingHandler.postDelayed(composingRunnable, 2000);
```